# Sql lite where class error

Tags: android, sqlite, where-clause

I want to get specific data from table ..I have inserted query but its giving me error...and my app will crash...
Activity code is

```
public Cursor getpicSpecfic(String st)
    {
        return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE_PIC, 
                new String[] {"id", "pic_name", "pic_place","pic_fellows","pic_purpose","pic_location","pic_jeoPoint_longi","pic_jeoPoint_lati","pic_sd_card","pic_time","pic_date"}, 
            "pic_name"+"="+st, null, null, null, null);
    }
```

while the error in the logcat is

```
01-31 01:43:13.033: E/AndroidRuntime(877): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.imagegallary/com.example.imagegallary.FullImageDetail}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: nnn (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT id, pic_name, pic_place, pic_fellows, pic_purpose, pic_location, pic_jeoPoint_longi, pic_jeoPoint_lati, pic_sd_card, pic_time, pic_date FROM Img WHERE pic_name=nnn
```

i am passing a string nnn which is pic name ..i have seen through sqllite browser that this will nnn exist...any help

Comment: enclose nnn into single quotes: "pic_name='" + st + "'".

Comment: why do people never use selectionArgs ?

Answer (score 0):

A very common mistake.
Try adding `' '` around st like this:

```
public Cursor getpicSpecfic(String st)
    {
        return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE_PIC, 
                new String[] {"id", "pic_name", "pic_place","pic_fellows","pic_purpose","pic_location","pic_jeoPoint_longi","pic_jeoPoint_lati","pic_sd_card","pic_time","pic_date"}, 
            "pic_name"+"='"+st + "'", null, null, null, null);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this way by adding the single quote `' '` to your passing value of where criteria as below:

> ```
> public Cursor getpicSpecfic(String st)
> {
>     return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE_PIC, 
>             new String[] {"id", "pic_name", "pic_place","pic_fellows","pic_purpose","pic_location","pic_jeoPoint_longi","pic_jeoPoint_lati","pic_sd_card","pic_time","pic_date"}, 
>         "pic_name"+"="+ "'" + st + "'", null, null, null, null); <<--- see the difference in this line.
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

in the `query()` method, there is a parameter largely overlooked, given the number of questions asked here that result directly from not using it.

`selectionArgs` is a list of arguments that will be prepared and inserted in the query. Using it is very good because it protects the query from any kind of injection (voluntary or not) and escapes everything. Moreover, it (theorically) can help the Database optimize queries by recognizing queries that are the same with different args.

It also simplifies queries by making them args free, hence succeptible of being grouped, made constants and reviewed independently.

It is used as follows :

```
String[] projection = {...}; // your projection
String selection = "pic_name = ?"; // ? is replaced by the selectionArgs in order
String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { st }; // no need to quote, escape or anything
Cursor res = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE_PIC, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
```